# Using repmat() to equalise the length of two audio files Matlab

Tags: matlab

Having a slight issue with the repmat() function.

I've got two audio files that I'm using for cross synthesis in Matlab, I want to make the second audio file repeat so it's the same length as the first one.

Currently I'm doing

```
c = size(y());
rep = y2(1:end,:);
y(1:end,:) = repmat(rep,1, c(1))
```

Yet it's not making a 1D matrix, any suggestions?

y and y2 are just the y values of each song converted to mono.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the dimensions of `y` and `y2`?

Comment: I actually managed to solve it myself, turns out I was using them in the wrong order, needed to be repmat(rep c(1), 1)!

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to solve it myself, turns out I was using them in the wrong order, needed to be repmat(rep c(1), 1)!